# Cypher Neo4j ORDER BY DESC query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to order the COUNT(Movie.title) in descending order.
But it gives an error.
This is the query.

```
MATCH (Movie {genre:"Action"})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(Person)
                 "RETURN Person.name, Movie.genre,  COUNT(Movie.title)"
                 "ORDER BY COUNT(Movie.title) DESC"
                 "LIMIT 100";
```

Thanks!

Comment: I get no error when trying this query (without the superfluous quote characters in lines 2-4) with version 2.1.5.

Comment: you should probably also share the error

Comment: Friendly reminder to everyone, the `order by` must before `limit`. this is why I go to this page every time.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {genre:"Action"})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(person:Person)
RETURN person.name, movie.genre,  COUNT(distinct movie.title) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is returned because you cannot order by an aggregate immediately in Cypher. To order by any aggregate you need to use the [WITH](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html) operator.

So your query should be (assumes that you want to list the titles per actor per genre):

```
MATCH (Movie {genre:"Action"})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(Person)
RETURN Person.name, Movie.genre,  COUNT(Movie.title)
WITH Person.name AS name, Movie.genre AS genre, COLLECT(Movie.title) AS titles
RETURN name, genre, titles
ORDER BY LENGTH(titles) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The limit 100 has now changed its behaviour so you probably want to move it up into the query:

```
MATCH (Movie {genre:"Action"})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(Person)
RETURN Person.name, Movie.genre,  COUNT(Movie.title)
WITH Person, Movie
LIMIT 100
WITH Person.name AS name, Movie.genre AS genre, COLLECT(Movie.title) AS titles
RETURN name, genre, titles
ORDER BY LENGTH(titles) DESC
```

Aside: to make your queries perform well you should have an Index on the Movie.genre property and you should introduce labels for Movie and Person.